# Finding closest value to 0.50 in R-vector

Tags: r, vector, closest

I have a vector that will have decimals between 0 and 1. I want to find which element/entry in the vector that is closest to 0.50.

Are there any built-in ways in R that make this easier than looping through and comparing as one would normally do in other languages?

For example in: `results num[1:4] 0.0223 0.416 0.514 0.701`, I want to get the 3rd element from results as it's closest to 0.50.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
x <- c(0.0223, 0.416, 0.514, 0.701)

x[which.min(abs(x-0.50))]

[1] 0.514
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So if I have understood correctly, if I remove the x I get the index of that element?

Comment: Exactly, that is how it works :)